# Firewall rules block DNS from working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I've set up firewall rules on my server, which are generally working well. However, there's an issue: my server can't ping any website. It seems to be a DNS problem that arises when these rules are active. I get the following error when trying to ping:

`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

This issue disappears when I disable the firewall rules. I've even tried allowing outgoing connections to Google's and Cloudflare's DNS servers (which my server uses) by adding specific rules, but the problem persists. Here are the rules I've configured:

```
sudo ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set allowed_countries_ipv4 src -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -I INPUT -m set --match-set allowed_countries_ipv6 src -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# OUTPUT chain rules for DNS
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d 2001:4860:4860::8888 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d 2001:4860:4860::8888 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d 2606:4700:4700::1111 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -d 2606:4700:4700::1111 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Could I be missing something? Any suggestions on what else to try would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably. Does your `/etc/resolv.conf` actually point at `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1`, or do you have a local resolver based on systemd, which is most common in modern distros?

Comment: Can you ping by IP address, eg 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Are these the only rules you have got in place? If not, what DROP/REJECT rules are there and where in the order do they come

Comment: @tink /etc/resolv.conf points to 127.0.0.53. `resolvectl status` outputs: Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8. @Chris Davies - I can ping these IPs. And those are the only rules I have..

Comment: Thanks to @tink 's comment I allowed the loopback interface explicitly: sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT - I don't understand why it's necessary though, I thought the internal traffic is allowed anyways. Which of the above mentioned rules should I now keep, what is "best practice"? Thanks!